# in bot framework how to fix issue while debugging facebook messenger channel with ngrok

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to debug my bot framework using Facebook messenger channel.

I am using ngrok to test locally. Now when the user (who is an admin for the Facebook page) enters a message in messenger it reaches properly to my localhost and breakpoints are getting hit. But the problem is that the response from the bot is not going back to messenger, nothing is getting displayed in FB messenger.

For debugging I also want the response from bot should be displayed on FB messenger. I have also looked at other responses but I tried all, nothing working

Comment: Quick check on your side: are you sure you select all the checkboxes on Messenger setting

Comment: Issue is fixed. My microsoft appid and password in bot code was incorrect.